# Static methods in a repository class?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

When using the [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) for my data handling classes, I have found myself in a scenario in which I seem to be repeating some chunks of code. I tend to only use instance methods and can't seem to reference other instance methods within the same class but feel static methods would solve this problem, so I'm just wondering if there is any downsides or things to be aware of when using static methods in a repository class, or perhaps if there is a better solution?

It seems to me to be a perfectly logical thing to do, but I just have not seen examples of it being done before.

```
private DocumentEntities db = new DocumentEntities();

int ExampleRepository.GetDocumentScore(Document doc)
{
    return GetDocScore(doc);
}

int ExampleRepository.GetOverallScore()
{
    int overallScore = 0;

    foreach(Document doc in db.Documents)
    {
        overallScore += GetDocScore(doc);
    }

    return overallScore;
}

private static int GetDocScore(Document doc)
{
    int docScore = 0;

    // some logic to work out a documents score from it's results

    return docScore;
}
```

Comment: if `GetDocumentScore` would never participate in any downstream abstractions / DI / etc - if it doesn't depend on anything, then sure: static is fine; it *does* mean it can't be `virtual`, but: I'm of the opinion that things shouldn't be virtual by default - but: virtual when needed and tested

Comment: Private static methods are fine, just don't make them public and you're not violating any OOP rules. The only question is whether the value of a "document score" is some sort of a business rule, or it's supposed to be a fixed computed value for this entity (and then it makes sense to make `GetDocScore` a property in `Document`).

Comment: In this scenario, Document objects have Result objects which in turn have a Correct property of true / false. The GetDocScore uses some logic to work out the documents percentage score using the Document.Results.Correct values.

The logic only requires this Document and it's Results, and nothing more. Is this something I should be adding to the Document class then? If so, the only issue is that I'm using EFCode First so if I have to regenerate the Document class, my own code will disappear, so I assume I should be putting this kind of logic in a Document partial class along with my Metadata?